# How to construct dynamically attribute name in xhtml - JSF

Tags: jsf, jstl, managed-bean

I want to assign a dynamic value to an input in xhtml page. The ManagedBean contains 3 string attributes: customField1, customField2 and customField3

In the xhtml page I'm looping over a list of values to custruct components:

```
<ui:repeat  value="#{listBean.customFields}" var="item" varStatus="status">
<div >
    <p:outputLabel value="#{item.label}" />
    <br />
    <c:set var="test" value="#{'myBean.customField'.concat(status.index)}"/>

    <p:inputText value="#{test}"   />
</div>
</ui:repeat>
```

What I did for concatenation does not work since it concider that the whole expression is a String so it is unable to bind "#{test}" with the bean attribute.

You think it is possible to do that in jsf ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: cant you just do `value="#{myBean.customField}#{status.index}"`

Comment: I tried that..It does not work =>javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: page.xhtml  value="#{myBean.customField}#{status.index}": The class 'com.xxx.yyy.zzz.MyBean' does not have the property 'customField'

Comment: does customField have public getters/setters in your backing bean?

Comment: the backing bean contains only customField1, customField2 and customField3  with public getters and setters

Comment: Please ignore comments of j.con. He clearly came here along [java] tag (which Kukeltje rightfully removed) and is merely doing blind guesses. In future JSF questions, please don't use [java] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
<p:inputText value="#{myBean['customField'.concat(status.index)]}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..that does not work : javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: page.xhtml value="#{myBean.customField}#{status.index}": The class 'com.xxx.yyy.zzz.MyBean' does not have the property 'customField'. By the way, on the xhtml there was a warning about EL syntax starting at concat

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code in answer.

Comment: Sorry ! you are right ! I think it works et does the binding correctly. However, since I have only customField1, customField2 and customField3 I put  #{myBean['customField'.concat(status.index+1)]} and I got this error message : The class 'com.xxx.yyy.zzz.MyBean' does not have the property 'customField4'. Note that customFields contains only 3 elements... I do not understand why it is going until customField4 despite the length of the list = 3. When displaying the EL expression I got 1 , 2 and 3 ! I'm confused.. Why it is doing an additional iteration in the binding ?